# Why are some flags not highlighted in red?

Tags: bug, flagging

I noticed today that most of the posts in my "Flagged Posts" tab are highlighted in a light red shade but one of them weren't highlighted.

Does it mean anything or it is a site bug?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posts highlighted in red have been deleted. Posts not highlighted are still visible to ordinary users on the site.